# Verdana font not working same in every browser

Tags: fonts, cross-browser

I used verdana font in my site. There is some different between firefox and chrome browser. Previously asked that question, but unfortunately i didn't get the answer. Now when i saw the font in firefox its spacing is more than the chrome.Is there any better solution to get the problem resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you do some sort of css reset for letter spacing?

try:

```
* { letter-spacing:0px; }
```

at the top of your css or in your 'css reset' file if using